# Stuck on Ubuntu logo

Tags: 12.10

I installed ubuntu 12.10 along side my Windows 7. When it was done installing I restarted the computer and chose ubuntu from the boot loader and now when I goes to the purple screen with Ubuntu logo and the dots under it, it just gets stuck there... I've left it alone for a long time and still nothing. Any one got any ideas I can try? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long, and how did you install?

Comment: Did you install it with Wubi or with a normal installation?

Comment: I installed with a Cd and with a normal install.

Answer (score 0):

hold the Enter key until you see some any change, I have a similar problem and resolve it, I think is a problem with the ahci mode, but I have more than a year without try to solved it.